Comparing hash of a file in git index versus git working directory is inconsistent
I have a git repo with the same file called fileA in two different paths : locationX and location Y.
I am trying to ensure that these two files are identical and if they do/do not match what's been committed;
ie

working directory - locationX/fileA == locationY/fileA
committed file    - locationX/fileA == locationY/fileA

To facilitate this comparison I have tried comparing the hash of a file in the git working tree (using git hash-object) versus the hash of the same file in the git index (using git ls-files -s). The problem is that I get inconsistent results.
When i use these two git commands, for some files I get the same hash, but for other files it produces dissimilar hashes.
so why is there a disparity?
Hers my inelegant PowerShell script:
write-host "==================FILE 3 ======================="
$repo_path                 = "h:/product_axiom/fpga_mbrd/source/fpga_mbrd" 
$full_file_path            = "h:/product_axiom/fpga_mbrd/source/fpga_mbrd/rtl/src/fred2.txt"
Push-Location $repo_path
$sha_of_image_in_index                           = [regex]::match($(run_command -command "git ls-files -s              $full_file_path"),'^\w*\s*(\w*)\s*.*$').groups[1].value
$sha_of_image_in_workingtree                     =                $(run_command -command "git hash-object --no-filters $full_file_path")
$sha_of_image_in_workingtree_filters             =                $(run_command -command "git hash-object              $full_file_path")
write-host "repo_pathname                      =<$repo_path>"
write-host "Filepathname                       =<$full_file_path>"
write-host "sha_of_file_in_index               =<$sha_of_image_in_index>"              
write-host "sha_of_file_in_workingtree         =<$sha_of_image_in_workingtree>"        
write-host "sha_of_file_in_workingtree_filters =<$sha_of_image_in_workingtree_filters>"
run_command -command "git log  --all -m --find-object (git hash-object $full_file_path)"
Pop-Location

write-host "==================FILE 4 ======================="
$repo_path                 = "h:/product_axiom/fpga_mbrd/source/fpga_mbrd" 
$full_file_path            = "h:/product_axiom/fpga_mbrd/source/fpga_mbrd/rtl/src/mbrd_pkg.vhd"
Push-Location $repo_path
$sha_of_image_in_index                           = [regex]::match($(run_command -command "git ls-files -s              $full_file_path"),'^\w*\s*(\w*)\s*.*$').groups[1].value
$sha_of_image_in_workingtree                     =                $(run_command -command "git hash-object --no-filters $full_file_path")
$sha_of_image_in_workingtree_filters             =                $(run_command -command "git hash-object              $full_file_path")
write-host "repo_pathname                      =<$repo_path>"
write-host "Filepathname                       =<$full_file_path>"
write-host "sha_of_file_in_index               =<$sha_of_image_in_index>"              
write-host "sha_of_file_in_workingtree         =<$sha_of_image_in_workingtree>"        
write-host "sha_of_file_in_workingtree_filters =<$sha_of_image_in_workingtree_filters>"
Pop-Location

and here is the result
==================FILE 3 =======================
repo_pathname                      =<h:/product_axiom/fpga_mbrd/source/fpga_mbrd>
Filepathname                       =<h:/product_axiom/fpga_mbrd/source/fpga_mbrd/rtl/src/fred2.txt>
sha_of_file_in_index               =<147421d28e8afde77923263215ecc1eb374c2cd0>
sha_of_file_in_workingtree         =<6e8276fcb65c60902ea5c5fec9f96d3e46ccf0b2>
sha_of_file_in_workingtree_filters =<6e8276fcb65c60902ea5c5fec9f96d3e46ccf0b2>
==================FILE 4 =======================
repo_pathname                      =<h:/product_axiom/fpga_mbrd/source/fpga_mbrd>
Filepathname                       =<h:/product_axiom/fpga_mbrd/source/fpga_mbrd/rtl/src/mbrd_pkg.vhd>
sha_of_file_in_index               =<c843c0b30a9ba5873fdc1ddf7c9989a75ff9b735>
sha_of_file_in_workingtree         =<c843c0b30a9ba5873fdc1ddf7c9989a75ff9b735>
sha_of_file_in_workingtree_filters =<c843c0b30a9ba5873fdc1ddf7c9989a75ff9b735>




You are adding a layer of complexity by showing us the script instead of the git commands that were run. Could you provide the git commands that were run and their outputs?

Adding a file then changing it would produce this. Do git check-attr -a $path to see any attributes Git's seeing, looking for eol/crlf processing and explicit filters but -a is easiest. And yeah, performative syntax and needless generalization makes reading through code like wading in lard, lose the rococo. Blueprints and a geological survey for a doghouse might be fine as pedagogical devices in a classroom setting but they're out of place when they're not the point.

@eftshift0, my apologies for not making it clearer. The git commands are   git hash-object (with and without the --no-filters option) and.  git ls-files -s

@jthill apologies for making my post cluttered.

Well, the behavior can be produced by the sequence I gave, but there's still other possibilities, to eliminate them it'd be helpful if you stripped out the 80% of your question body that's completely irrelevant here and added the relevant details, the ones we asked for.   All I see is the fred2.txt you added isn't what's in your work tree, and filters don't seem to be affecting anything so it's a straight content difference. If there's something else going on maybe stripping out all the noise will make it clearer to everyone.

@jthill I tried using git check-attr -a $path  and saw no response on the command line

Not seeing any evidence the files are actually the same here.  Only thing I can think is you mixed adding with setting/resetting core.eol and/or core.autocrlf and your added content has or does not have crlfs that your current settings don't touch.
